# What are all the references in UNIKONG? (Spoilers?)

Tags: discussion, unikong

I get some of them but I'm a bit of a lapsed SO'er so some I'm not sure of, or if there is a reference.

- J. Skeet: [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)
- Level design/inspiration: [Donkey Kong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donkey_Kong_(video_game))
- Coins: [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-are-badges)
- Score: [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)
- Bombs: [downvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)
- Unikong itself: [unicorns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19479/225304). Also, [unicorns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19479#19479)
- Blue diamonds: moderator badges?
- Background city: Maybe NYC???
- Trolls: ??? mean SO users? People who can't spell?

Comment: *"Why unicorns?"* [Why ***not*** unicorns?!?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19479/225304)

Comment: WHY UNICORNS?! HOW DARE YOU ASK

Comment: Who's John Skeet? @JonSkeet 's evil twin?

Comment: [What Happens When You Reach 200k Reputation?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/what-happens-when-you-reach-200k-reputation/)

Comment: Donkey Kong + PacMan IMHO

Comment: My first name doesn't have an H in it and my boss still sends me emails that read John..instead of Jon...sigh!

Comment: I find it funny that Jon Skeet had to correct his own name in this post.

Comment: oh goddammit. sorry Jon

Comment: I'm  'James Martin' in so many places round the world that I just accept it now and don't bother to correct.  It's all Outlook's fault ,(from decades ago when some companies actually used it).

Comment: Skeet is Luigi from Super Mario 2, judging by his jumping skills.

Comment: It's a reference to the claims the site suffers from gamification.

Comment: There is [a question on Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/261044/who-do-the-top-scores-refer-to) which lists what the top scores refer to.

Comment: @JustDoIt Reading your comment I went to see the edit history, and oh gosh, *the* Jon Skeet had to come down here to correct his name!

Answer (score 32):

There's an easter egg which uses two common references.

> Enable sound, then press [`↑` `↑` `↓` `↓` `←` `→` `←` `→` `B` `A` `Enter`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konami_Code) to hear [a fun tune](https://www.youtube.com/watch?u=R5fRf-tgILU&w=&Jd1RjJVJYtI&v=dQw4w9WgXcQ).

See also [this related question on Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/260988/481).

Comment: omg yesss, that makes it so much more playable!

Comment: I must be really dense, but how does this work? I entered the sequence at the intro screen and while playing the game but... nothing.

Comment: @JAtkin I was being deliberately vague, but I've updated the post now: you need to press `Enter` at the end of the sequence.

Comment: I avoided it for so many years... I've finally been rickrolled...

Comment: OMG I tried the Konami code but forgot to finish it with <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: @dthree excellent. Our work here is complete.

Comment: Oh wow. the Konami code is in there as well. Awesome